# What setting do I need to find to fix this?

Tags: php

I'm running the same code on two different servers and I'm getting a different result.  I'm not sure what I need to change to fix this.

I'm working with a timestamp and I'm using the following.

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
echo $timestamp;
```

When I do that from my local test server running PHP 5.4.16 I get a value like: 1376732353181

When I run the same thing from my live server running PHP 5.3.6 I a value like: 1.37673257778E+12

I need my live server to act the same way as my test server and I'm not sure what's causing the difference.

The problem seems to occur at the point of multiplying by 1000 and getting a large number.  My local server gives me a regular number back while the other server gives me a decimal with E+12 on the end.  I forgot what that's called..??  I don't want it, though.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: A workaround will be to just use intval to avoid getting floating point representation.

Comment: @Xonar: Multiplying a timestamp by 1000 will push you into float territory unless PHP is 64-bit.

Comment: @Xonar, that works for me.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah. @Andrew Is both your local server and live server running the same PHP version?

Comment: @Xonar, no.  I mentioned in the original post that the one working the way I wanted is running 5.4.16 and the other is running 5.3.6. intval() is solving the issue for me, though.

Comment: Posted the answer. My question was a bit vague. Was actually asking about bitness, but I talked about that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use intval to avoid getting floating point representation (if your PHP is 64-bit)

PHP 32-bit can't store a int larger than 2147483647 (Thanks Jon) so just be aware of that. If you need it to react the same regardless of environment then perhaps you should use floats for both of them.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a decimal digit representation of the result with

```
printf("%.0f", round(microtime(true) * 1000));
```

There's also `sprintf` if you want the result to go into a variable.